# Using jQuery jslint error: '$' is not defined

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using JQuery with Angular. Everything works fine except I keep getting errors in JSLint saying `'$' is not defined.`. My controllers look something like this:

```
function controllerFunc($scope) {
    // Stuff goes in here
};
angular.module('core').controller('controllerName', ['$scope', controllerFunc]);
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add this comment at the top of your .js file:

```
/*global $ */
```

That tells JSLint that `$` is a global defined in some other file, so it can calm down. I find that I need to use this anytime I have a JavaScript file that is jQuery-dependent. The same principle works when you have broken code into multiple .js files, like this:

```
// foo.js
function foo() {
    return 'Hello world!';
}


// bar.js
/*global foo */
function bar() {
    return foo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're using it with angular, you maybe getting these errors becaus of dependency problems, make sure that the jquery it's already loaded where you're trying to use it. (i've never used angular but i use backbone, and i include my plugins with require.js, and many times i got this same error because of the dependeces haven't been loaded on the system, make sure that jQuery has been loaded befor you call your code and functions)

---

On require.js (Which i don't know if your're using) i specify at one part, everything that needs to be loadaded before my code gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

use `var $=jQuery();` in first line or `jQuery.noConflict()` in first and then use `jQuery` insted of `$` in your code.

```
var $ = jQuery();
//DO YOUR WORK HERE
```

or

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
...//DO YOUR WORK HERE
}
```